# How do you set up Node to open n shells and execute n commands synchronously?

Tags: javascript, shell

I'm writing a test suite that requires a proxy to be booted up, and then a curl POST request needs to be made to the proxy **once it is live**.

**This is simple to do manually via two different tabs in the terminal eg**:

```
In one terminal window: sh ./proxy/bin/yourProxy
```

```
In another terminal window: curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/proxy
```

This works, but I want to have this automated.

The issue I'm running into is that when I run the first shell command, a shell opens, but another shell never opens - and I need two different shells - one for each command.

I've tried using the concurrently npm module and using sleep to make the commands synchronous - no luck

**I'm exploring using node. I've tried node's spawn, exec, and execSync. Here's an example using spawn:**

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

const childOne = spawn("/bin/sh", [ "-c", "curl http://www.google.com" ])
const childTwo = spawn("/bin/sh", [ "-c", "curl http://www.yahoo.com" ])

childOne.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  console.log(`childOne stdout:\n${data}`);
});

childTwo.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
  console.log(`childTwo stdout:\n${data}`);
});
```

This produces the result of curling childOne - but child2 shows a "redirect".

**Terminal output**:

```
child2 stdout:
redirect
child stdout:
expected output from curling google.com
```

**How do you set up Node to open n shells and execute n commands synchronously**?

Answer (score 0):

First you won't want need to do things such as running other processes, making network requests etc. synchronously, since they may block your main process and get your program stuck.

Second, there are no problems with the functions you've found: `spawn()` and `exec()` can run processes asynchronously, and `execSync()` does the same thing synchronously. The reason why `curl http://www.yahoo.com` prints  `redirect` is that it IS a redirect. Try running it in your own shell, and you'll be able to find exactly the same output:

```sh
$ curl http://www.yahoo.com
redirect
```

Comment: brilliant - I should've tested the curl to see what the typical output was! I do need the actual processes I'm trying to run - to run synchronously - one is a proxy starting, and after it's running - i set the port with another command - but it must occur in a new shell.